# how to put an angular webapp into production

Tags: mysql, backend

I created my project in Angular, a Backend folder and a Frontend.
For the "Frontend" folder, I send it to production with ng build -prod and so far so good.
But for the "Backend"? And I also have a doubt about the service parameter.
What should I put in place of localhost: 3000?

"Backend" config.json

```
{
"development": {
    "username": "******",
    "password": "******",
    "database": "******",
    "host": "sql.twave.it",
    "dialect": "mysql"
},
"test": {
    "username": "******",
    "password": "******",
    "database": "******",
    "host": "sql.******.it",
    "dialect": "mysql"
},
"production": {
    "username": "******",
    "password": "******",
    "database": "******",
    "host": "sql.******.it",
    "dialect": "mysql"
}
```

}

"Frontend" comuni.service.ts

```
    export class ComuniService {
    
  baseURL = 'http://localhost:3000/comuni';
    
      constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
    
      getData() {
        return this.http.get<Array<Comuni>>(this.baseURL)
      }
    
      getEntry(id) {
        return this.http.get<Comuni>(this.baseURL + "/" + id)
      }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. `Angular` is a front-end framework, you are using something else for backend, probably `Express` Can you provide more details and focus on your backend framework and your specific problem?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so you've to take care of a few things both in the Backend, Frontend.

Also, make use of `http-server` module in angular to debug before going live.

1. Make use of the typescript file in angular called `environment.ts` as well as `environment.prod.ts` instead of using a constant in your service for storing the `baseURL`.

Using environment.ts will allow you to create base-url for development while it automatically maps to prod.ts for production.

2. Use environment variables for your backend (presuming it is done in Nodejs, use dotenv to create env variables in dev mode).
3. Given your production environment, you can use `https://yourdomain.here:port_if_available` as the base-url for http-services.